# Ng-route works in pc but not in emulator (cordova)

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ngroute

When i run my project from my host (using chrome), it is working with all navigations without any error.

But when i run it on GenyMotion emulator, it doesn't have a go. Except when i give the template as a string, not as URL:

```
var myApp= angular.module('MyApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngMaterial'
]);
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
            .when('/test', { /////////////////////////THIS IS WORKING
                template : '<span> AHEY </span>',
                controller  : 'testController'
            })
            .when('/LoginPage', {/////////////////////////THIS IS NOT WORKING
                templateUrl : 'LoginPage.html',
                controller  : 'loginController'
            })
});
```

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="MyApp">

    <head>
        ...     
    </head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <body ng-controller="mainController">
        <div id="header" layout="row" > </div>
        <div ng-view></div>
        <script> .... </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you check please adb logcat -c in  command prompt?

Comment: if i write `adb logcat -c` i take nothing. but i have a running logcat and that says: `no content-security-policy meta tag found. please add one when using the whitelist plugin`. I don't know whether it is related to this problem?

Comment: try  to android platform 19 and make build and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason: **Case sensitiveness**

While an url is insensitively interpreted by js, it is not the case in android or in ios.

Thus, if everything is okay, please check the casEs in your path.